# How to return only the year and month from a SQL Server DateTime datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Returns: `2018-01-10 16:38:13.790`

I want that date part without the day and time part like `2018-01`

How can I get that?

Comment: Hint: `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`. This is very simple sql. Please give it a try and/or search google. There are tons of answers for this type of question.

Comment: Hint2: there is a even simpler way

Comment: Agree with @Phillip. I like your answers below better. :-) We all learn from each other! Thanks!

Comment: Of course, depending on what version of SQL Server you have, will determine if you can use `FORMAT` or `Convert` functions. The `Format` function is SQL 2012+.

Comment: @WEI_DBA is right its very basic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT ( GETDATE() , 'yyyy-MM' )
```

Ok so if you have a Table named MyTable with a Column named DateCol of Type DateTime you can use the query below:

```
SELECT FORMAT ( DateCol , 'yyyy-MM' ) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you @Phillip. Could you tell me also how can I use this if I have to get only year and month from sql  table

Comment: @TestMan: sure.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
select convert(char(7), getdate(), 120) yearMonth
```

Format 120 returns yyyy-mm-dd format.  Char(7) is used because you only need the year, hyphen, and month,

Comment: there is no need to convert to char(7) if you just use the format 'yyyy-MM'

Comment: True, but, format() is a new trick and I'm an old dog.